# CORS Issue: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Header Present on Laravel 10 API Request

Tags: php, laravel, axios, cors

I'm encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue when attempting to make a GET request from my React app to a Laravel API. The specific error I'm getting in the console is as follows:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://0748-102-146-2-29.ngrok-free.app/api/products-api' from origin 'http://localhost:19000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here are the relevant details of my setup:
Laravel API Configuration (config/cors.php):

```
return [
'paths' => ['api/*', 'http://localhost:19000', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
'allowed_methods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'], // Add other methods as needed
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
// ...
];
```

**React App (useProductFetch.js):**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const fetchData = async () => {
setIsLoading(true);

try {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://0748-102-146-2-29.ngrok- 
    free.app/api/products-api"
  );
  console.log("Axios request successful");

export default useProductFetch;
```

Postman Request:
When I send a GET request to the API endpoint https://0748-102-146-2-29.ngrok-free.app/api/products-api using Postman, I receive the expected response:

```
{
"data": [
    // ...
]
```

}

Issue:
Despite configuring CORS on the Laravel API to allow all origins and methods, I'm still facing CORS issues when making requests from my React app. I've also verified that the server is returning the expected response when accessed directly through Postman. like so "https://0748-102-146-2-29.ngrok-free.app/api/products-api"

Question:
What could be causing this CORS issue despite having the correct CORS configuration on my Laravel API? Is there something else I need to consider or any additional steps I should take to ensure that my React app can successfully make requests to the API? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: the request brings back 200 in the network tab but in the response headers the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is missing

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue with React and Laravel 10.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same while working on many projects of my own. You have to create a middleware to solve this issue. The below code is the middleware that I have been using. I've added your localhost URL in it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , 'http://localhost:19000');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
        $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

After creating the middleware you have to define the middleware on **app/Http/Kernel.php** file under **$routeMiddleware** array like:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...(Any previous middlewares)       

        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,

    ];
```

Once you have done this you can use it in your API route groups or any individual route that you have created. For example:

```
Route::middleware(['cors'])->prefix('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
});
```

Make sure to run *php artisan config:clear* command just to make sure there isn't any cached config for your application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not the proper solution. CORS has been built in to Laravel since v9 (currently v10 as of Sept. 2023).

Comment: I admit with @AimFireReady Laravel 10 and 9 must have its proper way of doing it. I have not found the solution yet even after reading the documentation thoroughly that is a workaround perhaps it may help. Thanks.

Comment: I never found the exact cause of my issue, but it was eventually resolved. I would be extra careful and advise clearing all cache before restarting the artisan dev server.

Comment: I have a clue on that. Sometimes Chrome do not send a Preflight request with Http OPTIONS method. And the Laravel 10 CORS implementation only return CORS Headers on OPTIONS requests. So that is why the CORS on the browser fails, because an OPTIONS request has never been sent before. The solution on this answer here is to send the CORS header in EVERY request, even if is not an OPTIONS method. You can check that on vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php on line 64.

Answer (score -2):

You can install **Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin** Chrome extension to solve this issue.